# The contents of a FrontPage component have been modified

Tags: troubleshooting, microsoft-expression, frontpage

I get this message intermittently with Microsoft Web Expression 3:

> The contents of a FrontPage component have been modified. These contents will be overwritten when you save this page.

I have read kb/219873, but it did not help.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Include pages are the cause of this error message.

While I have not come up with a definitive answer, I found that posting in the specialist Expression Web forum helped.  There are good people dedicated to Expresson over there.  (Just as there are wonderful people at this site).